# Javax-based Transactional Does NOT Rollback As Intended

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a SpringBoot rest application using jdbcTemplate and postGres database. There is a certain endpoint that is supposed to be executed as an atomic transaction, or else rolled back. I am not getting the rollback to work as I had intended. I can't show the actual code, but I have a very simple example that fails the same way (below).

Here is the issue:  since this is set up as a transaction, I would have expected the first update in the Orders table to rollback (since the 2nd updated failed with exception), but it doesn't (PersonID remains null).

This example is VERY contrived, but it exactly replicates my issue. I simply need for the transaction to rollback the 1st update command.

I would rather the solution continue to use annotation-based transaction boundaries, rather than setting up the transaction in JDBC or similar in the java code. I would be grateful for any ideas. Thanks.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Repository
public class DeletionRepository {

@Autowired
protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
public int deleteWithCascade() {
    int status = 0;

    // this succeeds as expected because the PersonId field is nullable
    status = jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE Orders SET PersonId = NULL WHERE OrderID = 123");

    // this throws an integrity constraint violation because the PersonId field is NOT NULL
    status = jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE Reservations SET PersonId = NULL WHERE ReservationID = 123");

    // we never get here due to above exception
    status = jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM Persons WHERE PersonID = 'ABC123");
    return status
}
```

The exception is:

```
[UPDATE Reservations SET PersonId = NULL WHERE ReservationID = 123]; ERROR: null value in column \"personid\" violates not-null constraint\n  Detail: Failing row contains (123, hotel room, null).; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column \"personid\" violates not-null constraint\n  Detail: Failing row contains (123, hotel room, null)."
```

Here are the SQL commands for the test data the above example is using:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (personID varchar(45) NOT NULL, LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL, FirstName varchar(255), Age int, PRIMARY KEY (personID));
INSERT INTO Persons (personID, LastName, FirstName, Age) values ('ABC123', 'Jones', 'Janet', 35)

CREATE TABLE Orders (  OrderID int NOT NULL, OrderNumber int NOT NULL, PersonID varchar(45), PRIMARY KEY (OrderID), FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID));
INSERT INTO Orders (OrderID, OrderNumber, PersonID) values (123, 456, 'ABC123')

CREATE TABLE Reservations (  ReservationID int NOT NULL, ReservationDetail varchar(255), PersonID varchar(45) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ReservationID), FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID));
INSERT INTO Reservations (ReservationID, ReservationDetail, PersonID) values (123, 'hotel room', 'ABC123')
```

Update: based on initial feedback, I also tried below. It still did not roll back

```
import  org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
public class DeletionRepository {

@Autowired
protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

 @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public int deleteWithCascade() {
    int status = 0;
```

Comment: The import should be org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional.

Comment: @Mar-Z no, that did not work. Same result.

Comment: @EnableTransactionManagement annotation is present in configuration? Or equivalent like spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency.

Comment: A dumbed down code which doesn't show the actual issue, we love that here on stack overflow. If it doesn't work with the Spring `@Transactional` either this code isn't a fair representation of what you are trying to achieve. Maybe your class or method is `final`, it isn't `public` or you are creating a new instance of the repository yourself. Or you are calling this method from the same class instead of externally calling it. To be short there is far too little information here to help you. We need calling code, configuration and your full stacktrace and actual code (obfuscated is fine).

Comment: In additional some version of the Spring and Spring Boot would be good to know as well, as it depends on the version (ideally some dependency management of your maven or gradle build).

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't know why you say my dumbed down is not representative. If absolutely is I believe. If you copy and past all my code and set of a simple java app and database tables in postGres and it rolls back the way I am attempting, then you have demonstrated there is something different about your environment than mine. Otherwise I guess you are ASSUMING it will work in your environment. I gave the detailed information to see of other people get the same or different results. I think that is worthwhile.

Comment: @M.Deinum I wasn't saying it didn't work with the Spring annotation, I said it gets the same results as the javax Transactional. Also, class and method are public. No final either

Comment: You clearly stated in the comments that you have the same result, it didn't work. Also there is far too little code here for a working sample. As stated how are you calling this, what is your configuration like and what versions are you using. You also haven't shown a stack trace which holds crucial information. So with what little you posted here it is impossible to determine what is different or wrong in your setup.

Comment: @M.Deinum well, I got it to work in another project that may have different spring dependencies, so you made me think it through that it could be something with the various differences between the two projects, including one is java 8 and the other 11...

Comment: The java version shouldn't matter. The spring version could as older ones don't support the `javax.transaction.Transactional` howver you stated that it doesn't work with the Spring `@Transactional` either. could you include your calling code for the repository and if possible the stacktrace for the error you get? The latter generally contains valuable information.